# Circular Char Array Buffer - c

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, circular-buffer

I am using a char * array to make a buffer to move information from multiple mapping threads to a reducing thread. I need to make the array circular, however, i keep getting segmentation faults when the array runs out of room. How do I make the array circular? I currently have

```
for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
    int next = mr->nextIndex + j;
    if(next > 1023){
        next = 0;
    }
    mr->buffer[next] = temp[j];
}
```

The array is set up as,

```
new_mr->buffer = malloc(sizeof(char *) * MR_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

with the macro being 1024. Any help is appreciated.

temp is

```
char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

and it gets its value from

```
memcpy(temp, kv, i);
```

and kv is passed into the function from the main.

Comment: Not enough information. What is temp and what is i?

Comment: temp is a char pointer size of char *, i is the size of the data being copied to the buffer in bytes

Comment: temp is what? Show the code.

Comment: temp is being allocated to the size of a pointer, but is being indexed into as if it's an array of char?  That seems fishy.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

You're storing some data into there using `memcpy()` but the storage space is only `sizeof(char*)` which is 4 or 8 bytes.  You probably meant to use some other size there, e.g. the value of `i` you pass to `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *temp = malloc(sizeof (char *));
```

should be

```
char *temp = malloc(sizeof (char) * i); // sizeof (char) can be omitted
```

because `temp` is expected to point to an array of `char`.

---

```
mr->buffer[next] = temp[j];
```

should be

```
mr->buffer[next] = &temp[j];
```

because `mr->buffer[next]` is of type `char *`.